# Wrap C block in function. Beginner question

Tags: c++, c, function, getcwd

I found the C snippet to get the current working directory [from here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/CandCPP/223274/223274/help-with-getcwd/). Essentially, the code is:

```
char directory[_MAX_PATH];
getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory))
```

I want to abstract that into another function, in a different file (so it can be swapped out on different platforms if necessary).

Currently, I have in the external file

```
void getCurrentDirectory(char *directory) {
    getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory));
}
```

and in the main file

```
char directory[100];
getCurrentDirectory(directory);
printf("%s", *directory);
```

However, when printing to screen, I get nonsense (possibly trying to print memory location as a string?)

I'm sure it's something blindingly obvious to a non-beginner. What's going on?

**Edit:** I'm on Windows 7, btw

Thanks.

Comment: This is not C++, edited.

Comment: True. It's not. It will form part of a C++ program eventually. Thanks

Comment: @jv42 I guess it is because C++ is a superset of C (more or less), no?

Comment: @All Let's not start the debate again, this is using C lib functions, C style strings, C style console output, this is C. There are C++ ways of doing the same things.

Comment: @jv42: So he's doing C++ wrong.  Our duty then is to correct his C++.

Comment: @Benjamin that's somewhat beyond the scope of this question, is it not? What if someone was looking for the C way to do things, they come here, and all they see is "you're doing it wrong, use C++ properly instead"?

Comment: @badgerr: But he wasn't asking that.  He asked about C++.  Adam put the C++ tag on there, then jv42 removed it and replaced it with a C tag, which would prevent many people from even seeing the question who might be able to give him a better C++ solution.

Comment: @Benjamin fair enough. I just noticed the subject says C, and he refers to a "C snippet". That's enough to suggest it might be a C question I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theres a number of things that you are doing wrong here:

```
void getCurrentDirectory(char *directory) 
  {
      getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory));
  }
```

***Mistake 1:***

```
`sizeof(directory)`
```

gives you size of a pointer, to be precise, char *. Your intention is to pass size of the array, and not the pointer size.

***Mistake 2:***

```
`printf("%s", *directory);`
```

Passes first element of the array to the printf not the address of the array. Your intention is to print the entire array not just the first element.

***Corrected Solution***

You should be doing

```
void getCurrentDirectory(char *directory, size_t arrSize)  
{                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    getcwd(directory, arrSize);
}
```

Size of the array is passed explicitly so the function can just use it.

In the main while printing the contents of the array:

```
   printf("%s", directory);
```

Comment: That's the conclusion I've come to based on badgerr's answer. Without correcting #2, I got a segfault. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the size of a char* to getcwd, instead of the size of the array.

Pass a size parameter to your function.

```
void getCurrentDirectory(char *directory, size_t size) {
    getcwd(directory, size);
}
```

and then:

```
char directory[100];
getCurrentDirectory(directory, sizeof(directory));
printf("%s", *directory);
```

Also, if you're using Windows, you should probably change your array size to the predefined `MAX_PATH` to avoid a potential buffer overflow. getcwd takes a length, but I don't think all of the file functions do.

Comment: That works, only if I remove the * from the printf parameter. Also, where is MAX_PATH defined?

Comment: Sorry, it's in limits.h, but it's not really necessary for getcwd, as you give it a max length as a parameter already. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This line:
`printf("%s", *directory);`

should be:
`printf("%s", directory);`

You're passing in the first element (directory[0]) to the printf, not the pointer to the char array.

Answer (score 2):

If it's C++ I'd suggest using [boost::filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203159/is-there-a-c-equivalent-to-getcwd/2203694#2203694) if at all possible, which hides all of the underlying platform details *and* gives you C++ style interface instead of the buffer overflow prone C functions.

Comment: Thanks, will look into that. I've not got so far as figuring out properly how C++ does OOP yet, especially interfaces.

Comment: My general guideline for any C++ programing would be "prefer the C++ way". `getcwd`, `printf` and `char` strings instead of `std::string` are all contrary to that principle (and hence the "is this C++" discussion taking place on the question comments)

Answer (score 1):

You should be allocating the buffer locally (where the necessary
length is known, and the actual length needs to be known) and
returning a string:

```
std::string
getCurrentDirectory()
{
    char results[_MAX_PATH];
    if ( getcwd( results, sizeof(results) ) == NULL )
        throw std::ios_base::failure( "Could not get current directory" );
    return std::string( results );
}
```

Note too that `_MAX_PATH` is only a guess; the actual maximum is
not a compile time constant (since it depends on the file
system).  An implementation which takes this into account might
look something like:

```
std::string
getCurrentDirectory()
{
    long length = pathconf( ".", _PC_PATH_MAX );
    if ( length == -1 )
        throw std::ios_base::failure(
                "Could not determine necessary buffer length to get current directory" );
    std::string results( length, '\0' );
    if ( getcwd( &results[0], results.size() ) == NULL )
        throw std::ios_base::failure( "Could not get current directory" );
    results.resize( strlen( results.c_str() );
    return results;
}
```

This is probably overkill, however, if the program is only going
to be used on a personal system with no NFS or SMB mounted drives.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is C++, why not do this:

```
std::string getCurrentDirectory()
{
    char directory[_MAX_PATH] = {};
    getcwd(directory, sizeof(directory));
    return directory;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find out the size of a memory block pointed at by a pointer using `sizeof` like that. It will evaluate to the size of the pointer itself.

Change your function to:

```
void getCurrentDirectory(char *directory, size_t buf_max)
{
    getcwd(directory, buf_max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now to answer what you've asked:

When getcwd fails for some reason the contents of the array pointed to by `directory` (in your case) is undefined. Therefore, with your buggy implementation you will see junk in most cases. (Also, you should check return value from `getcwd`, it returns -1 when it fails)

Now, the reason for failure in your case is the size that you are specifying using `sizeof(directory)` is just the size of a pointer (which would likely to be 4) and characters in the name of current working directory you are trying to print are more than that. This will work fine for directory of size 3 or less.

And, finally many others here have already explained you how to possibly fix it.